# Unit testing for REST API using node Js

Tags: api, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I want to write unit testing for my REST API calls(Using mocha and chai).
Can anyone provide me better guide or any previously written code ,so that I can perform easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple guides through internet to start with `mocha` and `chai`. As, for example, the official documentation:

- [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/)
- [Chai documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/)

Using `npm` you can install both:

- Mocha: `npm install --save-dev mocha`
- Chai: `npm install chai`

Also, for HTTP you need [chai-http](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/): `npm install chai-http`

With this you can start to code your tests.

First of all, into your test file you need import packages

```js
var chai = require('chai'), chaiHttp = require('chai-http');

chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

And also use the assertion you want, for example:

`var expect = chai.expect;`.

Tests use this schema:

```js
describe('Test', () => {
    it("test1", () => {
    })

    it("test2", () => {
    })
})
```

Where `describe` is to declare a 'suite' of tests. And inside every suite you can place multiple tests, even another suite.

If you execute this code using `mocha yourFile.js` you will get:

```sh
Test
    √ test1
    √ test2
```

Now you can start to add routes to test. For example somthing like this:

```js
it("test1", () => {
    chai.request('yourURL')
    .get('/yourEndpoint')
    .query({value1: 'value1', value2: 'value2'})
    .end(function (err, res) {
        expect(err).to.be.null;
        expect(res).to.have.status(200);
    });
})
```

And if you want to use your own express app, you can use

```js
var app = require('../your/app')

... 

it("test1", () => {
    chai.request(app)
    ...
}
...
```

And also exists multiple more options describe into Chai documentation.

Comment: Thank you very much .I'll go through it.

Comment: You are welcome! With any doubt I can help you. Also if the answer solve your problem, mark it as accepted is appreciated.